# Почему указатель на объект класса не нужно разыменовывать при обращении к полям, а обычный нужно для доступа к переменной?

Tags: c++

```
b n(9);// создаю объект класса
b* m = &n;
cout << m->y;// выдаст 9
int j = 0;
int* g = &j;
cout << *g;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оператор стрелки - это синтаксический сахар, т.е. вещь, которая упрощает жизнь программисту. По сути, когда вы пишете `m->y`, вы пишете `(*m).y`, т.е. сначала разыменовываете указатель, а затем обращаетесь к полю объекта.

Comment: Это не синтаксический сахар, это именно что отдельно существующий [member access operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access)
Его, например, можно даже перегрузить.

Comment: Почему какой-то оператор для работы с какими либо объектами не может быть синтаксическим сахаром?

Comment: Про синтаксический сахар можно всегда сказать, во что он превращается. Про стрелку - нет, потому что ее могут перезагрузить.

Comment: Так я говорю именно про случай работы с указателями, а не про работу с рандомными классами, у которых можно перегрузить оператор...

Answer (score 3):

Оператор *стрелка* как раз и осуществляет разыменование.

Comment: поняла, спасибо